# What we can use in selenium to locate dynamic elements?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

In our Regression Suite At many places Xpath and CSS used. And Developers changing Class and many HTML elements frequently. So We need to fix XPATH or CSS Selectors every time.

What could be the solution?

We tried creating dynamic xpath but still after sometime we have to change that as well.

Comment: One approach is to use an element attribute, such as `test-id`, with a deterministic naming convention that can be used by the app and automation tests, e.g., `<input ... test-id="people[0].firstName" />`.

Comment: Please share snippets of HTML so I can look at certain solutions - also include parents and ancestors.